# How can I force Visualforce to include empty attributes which I have specified?

Tags: visualforce, html, html5

During my adventures trying to get a `<select required="required">` to *actually be required*, I [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25321180/1492485):

> If a select element has a required attribute specified, does not have a multiple attribute specified, and has a display size of 1; and if the value of the first option element in the select element's list of options (if any) is the empty string, and that option element's parent node is the select element (and not an optgroup element), then that option is the select element's placeholder label option.

So I changed my markup to mirror that:

```
<select required="required" ...>
    <option value="">--</option>
    ...
</select>
```

But unfortunatley it rendered as:

```
<select required="required" ...>
    <option>--</option>
    ...
</select>
```

And because `value=""` was stripped out, it no longer meets the specification for `<select required="required">`, and the form can be submitted with no value selected.

**How can I get the `value=""` attribute specification to stick?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is another way to do it w/o javascript:

Set the value to a VisualForce function that evaluates to nothing:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" >
<apex:form>
    <select required="required">
        <option value="{!IF(1=1,'','')}">--</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <apex:commandButton value="Test Submit" action="{!save}" />
</apex:form>
```

It will send the value attribute to the browser:
[image: HTML in browser]

The browser will require it now:

[image: Required on form submit]

Comment: I prefer `IF(true,...)` to `IF(1=1,...)`. Regardless, it is much better to avoid javascript than what I came to on my own.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but below is the workaround I found. I would be happy to find one which does not require Javascript.

Since I already had a page load listener, I simply appended to it:

```
(function (w) {
    "use strict";
    w.addEventListener("load", function () {
        [].forEach.call(
            document.querySelectorAll("option:not([value])"),
            function (element) { element.value = ''; }
        );
    }
})(window);
```